# Using Subprocess to run another python script

Tags: python, subprocess, pyinstaller, exe

I am a newbie to python and would like to seek some advice. I having a script now where the function of this script can only be executed after I run a command i.e. `python run trial.py`. However, I would like to automate this process by using a subprocess function in a new python file called 'run.py' to run the trial.py script.

After that, I would wish to convert run.py file into an exe file to ease the execution for other users.

I have tried to perform the below steps.

````
1. saved the scripts (trial.py & run.py) in same directory.
2. Execute both of the files in same conda virtual environment.
3. Successfully execute run.py by using ```subprocess.run('xxx run trial.py')```
4. Converted the run.py into an exe file
5. Tried to execute the exe file and it is running, but **failed** to show the output that suppose to be appeared after running trial.py.
````

Would like to seek advice is any steps on above did wrongly or need to be improvised? I need to deal with confidential data hence the easiest way I can do is by using pyinstaller to allow another user to execute.

Hope to hear some advice

**UPDATE**
I had tried to use the codes below,

```
import subprocess
import sys
from subprocess import PIPE, STDOUT

command ='python run trial.py'
run = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
```

Now the exe file is able to be generated and able to run, but it doesn't appear the expected output. It ended without any error message. It works well when I run the script in python..
Wish to hear advice from all of you..

Comment: just note that pyinstaller executables are trivially reverse engineered (you can turn the exe file back to the .py files easily) so it's recommended to not use pyinstaller if you are using it for security purposes, it just packages the interpreter and python files, it doesn't improve the security of your program.

Comment: i recommend you write a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem so people can actually answer this question.

Comment: hi @AhmedAEK, noted. However, the reason i creating the exe file is because the trial.py file is actually a webapp. But I doesn't want to deploy it via github, therefore trying with exe file instead

Answer (score 0):

With subprocess, you can try it:

```
command = 'Your command' # Example: command = 'python trial.py'
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr)
```

Comment: Hi @tai hoang, i tried the same method but it appears error saying ```unsupportedOperation: fileno```

Comment: hi @ taihong, i edited a bit on your codes and now its running, but the issue is the exe file doesn't show the expected output and the application ends without any error message. May I know is my code not correct?

Comment: @mayliew Can you post the code for me to see?

Answer (score 0):

> I would wish ... to ease the execution for other users.

As I've understood your case, using `subprocess` and making an `exe` file out of your python file (which is not an easy task) is not a good fit for you.

Instead, I recommend you to have a look at [`make files`](https://makefiletutorial.com/) as they are well-known for simplifying your commands.

for example you can have a make file like this:

```
run:
  python trial.py
```

And users can simply run `make run`, and `python trial.py` will run instead.

The possibilities are endless.

---

You can also make a bash file that is an executable,

```bash
# !/bin/bash

python trial.py
```

And it will simply run like `exe` files.

Comment: hi @Arsham, ya i do understand it will be difficult to use subprocess and making it into exe file. Noted on your suggestion, however, what if the case is that my user is a non IT personnel and might be difficult for them to use the make run command?

Comment: @mayliew There are some solutions for that, first of all, why don't you make an exe file from trial.py itself? (why do you make another exe to run this py file?). Second, you can have an introduction (readme.md) and explain the commands and how to use them. Third, I personally prefer not to use Python for cases where I want to make some scripts or desktop applications for non-developers, but it's not a recommendation.

Comment: @mayliew I edited my answer and added another solution using bash scripts.

Comment: Hi @Arsham, thanks for the advice. I had tried to make an exe file from trial.py itself, but the problem is trial.py needs to be executed in another command that need to be done in anaconda prompt. I tried include the subprocess.run command in trial.py and made a exe and it becomes unlimited loop. Any suggestion on this?

Comment: for now bash file might be slightly difficult for me as I'm on windows, but bash file seems like need to use in Linux

Comment: hi @Arsham,  i updated the codes by referencing from taihong codes, but the issue is the exe file doesn't show the expected output and the application ends without any error message. May I know is my code not correct?

Comment: @mayliew I think you have more than one problem, and reproducing your problem is not possible with provided data (please provide more information). as I've already noticed, you are making a web application, is it with a known framework such as Django or FastAPI? and also I guess you want this web application to be used as a desktop application (but in the browser), am I right?

Comment: hi @Arsham, yes you're right, is streamlit app . want to have an exe file to trigger the app in browser